# Ошибка при pip install importlib

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

уважаемое сообщество!
Изучая [данную](https://realpython.com/python-sqlite-sqlalchemy/) статью, решил протестировать часть кода в PyCharm (работаю в Ubuntu). При импорте очередной библиотеки (pip install importlib) в виртуальном окружении через терминал, получаю ошибку:

```
Collecting importlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/77/3781f65cafe55480b56914def99022a5d2965a4bb269655c89ef2f1de3cd/importlib-1.0.4.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/varta/PP/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        import distutils.core
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
        from distutils.dist import Distribution
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
        from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
        import importlib.util
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-j3ru1kja/importlib/
```

естественно гуглил этот вопрос, к сожалению не нашел ответа. Вынужден обратиться к вам за помощью.

**UPD**

Как мне указал @andreymal, данная библиотека уже импортирована. В таком случаи, при выполнении [кода](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/python-sqlite-sqlalchemy/project/examples/example_1/main.py), все равно интерпретатор ругается на importlib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
  File "main2.py", line 98, in main
    with resources.path(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 184, in path
    package = _get_package(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 47, in _get_package
    module = import_module(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Comment: importlib это стандартный модуль, его не нужно устанавливать

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: @gil9red, хорошо, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @andreymal, посмотрите пожалуйста отредактированное сообщение.

Comment: Так ругается же не на importlib, а на project, который не установлен. А что такое project и почему он не установлен - этого уже не знает никто кроме вас

Comment: В [описании кода](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/python-sqlite-sqlalchemy/README.md) прописана установка, вы не забыли её сделать?

Comment: @andreymal, нет, я упустил этот шаг, сейчас посмотрел, и возникли вопросы. В описании есть команда $ pyenv install 3.8.0, мне не совсем не понятно что она делает. Устанавливает виртуальное окружение? Но я уже ставил его, согласно официальному мануалу python3 -m venv env (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Далее идет: Install a Python virtual environment for this project -  pyenv local 3.8.0 и python -m venv .venv (зачем точка перед .venv?).

Comment: @andreymal, подскажите пожалуйста, что именно устанавливает данная команда: Install the project: python -m pip install -e?

Comment: Данная команда - ничего, потому что вы забыли прописать, что именно устанавливать. В описании к коду указана команда `python -m pip install -e .` которая установит проект в текущем виртуальном окружении из текущего каталога по файлу setup.py

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115521/discussion-between-vartafather-and-andreymal).